# Accessing UserControl DataGrid within TabItem using WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I am very much in the learning process of WPF/MVVM and I have scanned other posts but have yet to come across someone doing what I am attempting to accomplish.

I have a `User Control` (View) called `Comp_Item.xaml` with the follow grid/datagrids each given a different name:

```
    <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
        <!-- Sectioning Columns and Rows -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="160"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Data Connection Section -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SectionTitleText_Style}" Margin="5,5,0,0" Text="Connections" />
            <DataGrid Name="connDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="3,30,3,3" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Output" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="*" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Discrete Outputs Section -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SectionTitleText_Style}" Margin="5,5,0,0" Text="Outputs" />
            <DataGrid Name="outDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="3,30,3,3" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Output" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="*" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Discrete Inputs Section -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SectionTitleText_Style}" Margin="5,5,0,0" Text="Inputs" />
            <DataGrid Name="inDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="3,30,3,3" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Output" Width="*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="*" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

I have another `User Control` (View) called `Dashboard.xaml` - which has a TabControl with 4 tabs of the `Comp_Item.xaml`

```
            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="4">
                <TabControl Margin="10">
                    <TabItem x:Name="comp1" Header="Computer 1" Style="{StaticResource TubeTabItem_Style}">
                        <view:Comp_Item/>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem x:Name="comp2" Header="Computer 2" Style="{StaticResource TubeTabItem_Style}">
                        <view:Comp_Item/>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem x:Name="comp3" Header="Computer 3" Style="{StaticResource TubeTabItem_Style}">
                        <view:Comp_Item/>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem x:Name="comp4" Header="Computer 4" Style="{StaticResource TubeTabItem_Style}">
                        <view:Comp_Item/>
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
            </Grid>
```

I then have a `View Model` (class) called `DashboardVM.cs` where I plan to do some connection related tests when a start button is pressed and then insert the results into the appropriate data table.

```
namespace TesterApp.ViewModel
{
    class DashboardVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        enum TestItemStatus
        { 
            Reset,
            Queued,
            InProgress,
            Pass,
            Fail
        }
    
        private string _StartButtonText;
        private bool isTestRunning;

        public DashboardVM()
        {
            _pageModel              = new PageModel();
            _StartButtonText        = "Start Test";
            StartButtonCommand      = new RelayCommand(o => StartButtonClick("StartButton"));
        }

        public ICommand StartButtonCommand { get; set; }

        private bool TestRunning
        {
            get { return isTestRunning; }
            set { isTestRunning = value;
                  if (isTestRunning) { StartButtonText = "Stop Test"; } 
                  else { StartButtonText = "Start Test";}
                  NotifyPropertyChanged("TestRunning"); 
                }
        }

        private void StartButtonClick(object sender)
        {
            if(TestRunning)
            {
                TestRunning = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Start program. 
                TestRunning = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an image view:
[image]

My goal here is lets say I test Computer 1's ethernet with a ping, I want to be able to insert the results into the table. Theoretically like `comp1.connDataGrid.Items.Add({"Ethernet", "8 Bytes", "Pass"});` - obviously I know that wont work but hopefully that gives an example of what I would like to be able to do. Is there a way to bind the data to successfully accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use Parent as a communication between Children (at least when we are talking about MVVM). My suggestion utilize some sort of messenger for those scenarios. For example if you are using MVVM, it is not a bad idea to utilize some third party library like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger
or write a messenger yourself (all you need is a subscribe, publish and receive messages).

Another option would be to have a global command or a Service for cross-ViewModel communication.